# skew unequal symbols

Tags: symbols

Suppose I arrange the numbers 40, 30, 20, 10 in the corner positions of a 3*3 array. To be precise, the number 40 (resp. 30, 20, 10) is located at the top-left (resp., bottom-left, top-right, bottom-right) corner. I have 3 questions:

Q1. How to type a symbol at the left-middle position to indicate that 40 is larger than or equal to 30? I think the symbol looks like of shape "V" together with a vertical bar aside (at the left or right side of the shape "V").

Q2. How to type a symbol in the middle position of the array to mean that 40 is larger than or equal to 10? I imagine that it appears like a skew "V" with it mouth pointing to 40, and with a bar aside again.

Q3. How to type a single symbol at the middle position, meaning that "40 is larger than or equal to 10, and 30 is larger than or equal to 20"? I hope it looks like a brute-force combination of the symbol from Q2 and its analog.

I need these folk math symbols in a beamer presentation. Wish someone kindly give me a collection of feasible TeX codes to do them, so that I can learn how to make such symbols in TeX. Or, are there ready-made codes in any TeX packages? Thanks in advance!

Here is an MWE:

Thanks Henri. Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
40 & > & 20\\
Q1 & Q2/Q3 & *\\
30 & > & 10
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\rotatebox` will do the trick.

Comment: The `\rotatebox` is perfectly adequate for your MWE however if you need arbitrary orientations for your symbol you may consider using TikZ (it does not load much extra stuff in beamer). Also, an [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) could be handy for Q3

Comment: Yes I see. Hasse diagram is also a way to do it. Thanks Bordaigorl!

Answer (score 6):

To answer Q1 and Q2, with the help of `\rotatebox` from `graphicx` you can define two new commands:

```
\newcommand{\rotgeq}{\mathrel{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\geq$}}‌}}
\newcommand{\rotmedgeq}{\mathrel{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{$\geq$}}​}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\rotgeq}{\mathrel{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\geq$}}‌}}
\newcommand{\rotmedgeq}{\mathrel{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{$\geq$}}​}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} 
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  40      & \geq       & 20 \\
  \rotgeq & \rotmedgeq & \rotgeq \\
  30      & \geq       & 10
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

About your Q3, it could be feasible, but it would result in an unintelligible symbol, so I suggest you not to use a similar thing.

Comment: Thanks for your solution and the suggestion, Karl! Actually you inspired me! Let me art it in Guru style.

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend to overlay two symbols. This will confuse the reader. You may help a bit by putting lines between your entries. Here is an example using [XY-pic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xypic) in order to give you an idea of what I mean:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\rotgeq}[1]{\text{\rotatebox{#1}{$\geq$}}‌}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{%
40 \ar[dd] _{\geq} \ar[rr] ^-{>} \ar[ddrr]  ^-(.75){\rotgeq{-45}} |!{[dd];[rr]}\hole & & 20 \ar[dd] ^-{\ast} \\
& & \\
30 \ar[rr] _{>} \ar[uurr]  ^-(.75){\rotgeq{45}} & & 10
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty-looking solution for the problem. Wishing a slide as concise as possible, I feel that removing the arrows might less distract the audiences. Thank you LaRiFaRi!

Comment: Please just add `@{-}` to every arrow in the code above. E.g. `40 \ar@{-}[dd]`. This and all other arrow styles can be read in the user guide http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyguide.pdf

Comment: beautiful: to the uninitiated, you can also replace documentclass ``amsart`` with (say) ``\documentclass{standalone}`` and ``\usepackage{amsmath}``